# "Тянуть волынку"

Tags: фразеология

Почему о промедлении говорят "тянуть волынку"? А еще "волынить"? При чем тут музыкальный инструмент, да еще и шотландский, а не наш?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не отыскивая ответ в этимологическом или фразеологическом словарях, позволю себе предположить, что у волынки протяжное, долгое звучание,которое способно при неумелом пользовании инструментом надоесть. Отсюда и известное выражение.

Answer (score 1):

Слово волынка это русское слово и в иностранных словах его нет.Если иностранцу скажете слово волынка он вас просто не поймет. От самой русской волынки у нас осталась ее часть дудка - жалейка. Если эту дудку вставить в бурдюк, то дудка - жалейка заиграет длительно и продолжительно подобно тому как "тянуть вола", волочить и тащить.Длительное звучание дудки за счет мешка - бурдюка этим помого создать Орган. Сам принцип работы меха волынки в дальнейшем взят за основу создания меха для гармошки, баяна и аккордеона. Если слово волынка у русских определяет их древнейший музыкальный инструмент, то позднее названия шотландской волынки это хайлэнд определяет еще и деревню, откуда собственно и вышла их средневековая волынка. А английское новейшее слово bagpipe, название волынки, указывает нам лишь о содержании в целом этого инструмента, как бэг - мешок, пайп - дудка.

Answer (score 0):

**Волынка** – традиционный музыкальный инструмент народов Европы и Азии. Стоит заметить, что волынки существовали и на Руси. Но были постепенно вытеснены гармонями и баянами. Волынка издает тягучие, монотонные звуки, которые стали обозначать медлительность и надоедливость, отсюда же пошло и слово *отлынивать*, то есть не выполнять свои обязанности.

Кстати, в русском языке у слова ТЯНУТЬ существует синоним ВОЛОЧИТЬ. Праслав. 
*volčiti «тащить» образовано с суф. -i-ti от сущ.* volkъ «перетаскивание» и «то, что тянут» (ср. укр. *волок* «бредень») > «место, по которому в старину перетаскивали суда», перен. также «промедление» (ср. от него в этом знач. рус. разг. *волокита* «нарочито-медлительное решение какой-либо задачи», в нем редкий суф. -ит-а). Сущ. *vоlkъ, давшее вост.-слав.* волок*, в древности образовано при чередов. e//o от глаг.* velkti «тащить».

Похоже (это лично мое мнение), что слово ВОЛЫНКА в выражении "тянуть волынку" появилось еще и по причине созвучности со словом ВОЛОЧИТЬ. Отсюда же и ВОЛЫНИТЬ. В результате смысл выражения "тянуть волынку" - это что-то типа "тянуть тянучку".